# multiple lines plot with ggplot, geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I want to plot multiple lines in the same chart. Each line represent an age group (grupo_edad). In the x axis is the week when the cases are notified (epiweek) and the y axis is the incidence rate (inc).

These is my data:

```
inc_015
```

When I use plotly the result is perfect:

```
p <- plot_ly()%>%
  layout(title = "Curvas de tasas de incidencia de casos notificados de COVID-19 \n en la Región Metropolitana, según grupo etario y semana epidemiológica primeros síntomas",
         xaxis = list(title = "Semana Epidemiológica"),
         yaxis = list (title = "Tasa x 100.000 habitantes") ) %>% 
  add_trace(x = inc_015$epiweek, y = inc_015$inc, type = 'scatter', mode = 'line', name = '0 a 15', 
            line=list(color='#16e3ff',dash='dashed')) %>% 
  add_trace(x = inc_1525$epiweek, y = inc_1525$inc, type = 'scatter', mode = 'line', name = '15 a 25',
            line=list(color='#00c9e4',dash='dashed'))
p
```

But when I try with ggplot the result is totally different, the points are connected vertically

```
ggplot(data=incidencia1,
       aes(x=epiweek, y=inc, colour=grupo_edad)) +
  geom_point()
```

Can someone tell me how to display the same graph that I made with plotly in ggplot2?

Comment: Hi. Firstly, `geom_point()` shouldn't be connecting points at all. `geom_line()` connects them in order of X. `geom_path()` connects them in order of appearance in the dataframe. Besides that, your ggplot2 code looks correct and should work as intended.

Comment: Secondly, your plotly example is not equivalent to the ggplot. Instead of colouring by a variable you are explicitly drawing two separate lines. You can always split your dataframe and draw two separate lines like you did for plotly.

Comment: Finally, it is difficult for people to recreate your example when you paste large tables. The output of `dput()` would have been very useful. Or in this case, the data looks like public covid data, so a link to the source would be the simplest option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ggplot2` you need to specify the `group` aesthetic in this case it is the same as `colour`

```
ggplot(data=incidencia1,
       aes(x=epiweek, y=inc, group=grupo_edad, colour=grupo_edad)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Comment: But isn't `group` automatically assigned as a combination of all the other aesthetics specified (`colour`, `fill`, `shape`, etc)? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html
Specifying `colour` should be enough. `group` only needs to be specified when you want to override the automatic grouping.

Comment: Not really - I will update the answers with some detail explaination regard the group with demo data.

Answer (score 0):

If there is someone that need the answer, here is the solution:

```
incidencia1$grupo_edad <- incidencia1$grupo_edad %>% as.factor()

f <- ggplot(data=incidencia1,
        aes(x=epiweek, y=inc, group=grupo_edad, col=grupo_edad)) +
        geom_path() + 
        scale_color_manual(name = 'Grupo Etario', labels = c("0-14", "15-24", '25-49', '50-64', '65-80', '>=80'), 
                                      values = c("#FDD700", 'red', "#FE882D", "darkolivegreen3", 'darkblue', 'deepskyblue3')) +
        theme_ipsum_rc(grid = 'Y') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
        xlab('Semana Epidemiológica') +
        ylab('Tasa de Incidencia') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
        labs(title = 'Curvas de tasas de incidencia de casos notificados de COVID-19', 
             subtitle = 'Región Metropolitana, según grupo etario y semana epidemiológica primeros síntomas')

f
```

thanks to @Sinh Nguyen and sorry for don't knnow how to label you