# Plotting multiple regression lines that belong to data from a specific column in a dataframe

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe of several plants with three measurements of their characteristics.

```
    plant_id  stem_id  stem_hei  inf_len
1       1       1       410      92
2       1       2       520     130
3       1       3       440      98
4       2       1       480     109
5       2       2       490     115
6       2       3       500     125
7       3       1       457     105
8       3       2       425      83
9       3       3       412      93
10      4       1       385     100
11      4       2       375      78
12      4       3       380      66
```

I put a simple **Stem height (x=stem_hei) vs Inflorescence length (y=inf_len)** plot for all of them and it's done without trouble.
[regression line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMTAu.png)

What I want is plotting three separate regression lines for the same relationship. But each one containing data for stem 1,2 and 3: *(line 1: data from stem 1, line 2: data from stem 2, same for line 3)*

I thought that using this function would select data by the values of stem_id, but it didn't:

```
  plot(tr_correl$tall_stem_hei, tr_correl$inf_len, "stem_id" == "1")
```

It may seem very obvious, but I don't really get how to go from here. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: this could work `plot(tr_correl1$tall_stem_hei[tr_correl1$stem_id==1], tr_correl1$inf_len[tr_correl1$stem_id==1])`. but you can draw all three regression lines more elegantly with `ggplot`

Comment: Hi! You data.frame is well structured to use the `geom_line()` layer of the `ggplot`plotting library.  You may find more information on the ggplot 2 official documentation or in this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66531066/10740287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with `ggplot2` package, using `geom_smooth`. You can change the regression type, show SE or not, and so on. Using the aesthetic `col` (and/or `linetype`) you can draw different lines for different group.

```
tr_correll <- data.table(stem_id=c("a","b","c"),tall_stem_hei=rnorm(9),inf_len=rnorm(9))

ggplot(tr_correll,aes(y=inf_len,x=tall_stem_hei,col=stem_id))+geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, it creates a single line plot, while I'm looking for are regression lines. Thanks for the suggestion anyway, I think ggplot is the path to go.

Comment: My bad, I was too hasty. Fixed

Comment: I'm not able to add the different lines. All I get is the points in a range of blue.
What is the need of the first codeline with data.table?

I'm using aesthetic ```col``` and linetype, but I don't know if correctly (asides that I don't have ```linetype``` function, only this one:


```ggplot(ilts, aes(y=inf_len, x=tall_stem_hei, col= stem_id, linetype_pal("stem_id")))+geom_point() + geom_smooth (method= "lm", se=F)+geom_smooth (data = ilts, method= "lm", se=F)```